# Lower bound on certain exponential sums and expressions related to them

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, fourier-analysis, analytic-number-theory

Let $$G(\alpha, x) = \sum_{n\le x}e(\alpha n^2)$$ Clearly, $r_k(n)$, the number of representations of a number as the sum of $k$ squares is given by the following expression:  $$r_k(n) = \int_0^1 G(\alpha, n)^k e(-\alpha n) d\alpha$$ However, the only bounds that I have seen on $G(\alpha, n)$ and to some extent $r_k(n)$ have been upper bounds. Does anyone know of any nontrivial lower bounds on $r_k(n)$, or asymptotic representations for $G(\alpha, n)$ if $|\alpha - \frac{a}{q}|\le \frac{\ln^B n }{n}$ and $q\le \ln^B n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are asking corresponds to estimating the exponential sum $$\sum_{n\leq N}e(\alpha n^{2})$$ on the Major arcs $$\mathfrak{M}_{q,a}=\left\{ \alpha\in[0,1]\ :\ \left|\alpha-\frac{a}{q}\right|\leq\frac{1}{N^{1-\eta}}\right\}$$  where $\eta\leq\frac{1}{10}.$ Note that this set is larger than what you are asking for, since I allowed $$\frac{N^{\eta}}{N}\text{ instead of }\frac{\left(\log N\right)^{B}}{N}.$$ I assume you were looking at the latter because that appears as the Major arcs in the proof of [Vinogradov's three prime theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vinogradov%27s_theorem). When working with [Waring's problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Waring%27s_problem), we are not constrained by the lack of uniformity in the prime number theorem for arithmetic progressions.

The Hardy-Littlewood Circle method tells us that for any $k\geq6,$ the number of representations of $n$ as a sum of $k$ squares asymptotically equals $$r_{k}(N)=\mathfrak{S}(N)\Gamma\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^{k}\Gamma\left(\frac{k}{2}\right)^{-1}N^{k/2-1}+O\left(N^{k/2-1-\delta}\right)$$ for an explicit $\delta>0$, where $\mathfrak{G}(N)$ is a constant called the singular series.

As usual let $e(x)=e^{2\pi ix}.$ Then for any $\alpha\in\mathfrak{M}_{q,a}$  $$\sum_{n\leq N}e\left(\alpha n^{2}\right)=\frac{1}{q}S_{a,q}T(\beta)+O\left(x^{2\eta}\right)$$ where $T(\beta)=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n\leq N}\frac{e(\beta n)}{\sqrt{n}}$ and $S_{a,q}=\sum_{n=1}^{q}e\left(\frac{a}{q}n^{k}\right).$ Note that the asymptotic comes from the Major arcs. The above quantities $T(\beta)$ and $S_{a,q}$ give rise to the so called singular integral $$\int_{0}^{1}T(\beta)^{k}e\left(-\beta x\right)d\beta=\Gamma\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^{k}\Gamma\left(\frac{k}{2}\right)^{-1}N^{k/2-1},$$ and singular series

$$\mathfrak{S}(N)=\sum_{q=1}^{\infty}\left(\sum_{\begin{array}{c}
a=1\\
(a,q)=1
\end{array}}^{q}\left(\frac{S_{a,q}}{q}\right)^{s}e\left(-\frac{a}{q}N\right)\right).$$

There are similar such expressions for writing $n$ as a sum of $s$ $k^{th}$ powers, and I recommend reading about the Hardy-Littlewood circle method applied to Waring's problem to find out more.

Comment: Thanks. The singular series was the sort of thing I was looking for.